# convert numpy array to AudioFileClip in MoviePy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, moviepy

I am trying to convert a numpy array of an audio file sampled at 44100 Hz into an AudioFileClip in MoviePy so I can overdub a videoFileClip. The online documentation is unclear on this topic.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant class is [`AudioArrayClip`](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/d4c9c37bc88261d8ed8b5d9b7c317d13b2cdf62e/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py#L213) in [`AudioClip.py`](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py).

Here are a couple of examples of how to generate 2 seconds of mono and stereo random noise:

```
import numpy as np
from moviepy.audio.AudioClip import AudioArrayClip

rate = 44100  # Sampling rate in samples per second.
duration = 2  # Duration in seconds

data_mono = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (int(duration*rate/2), 1))
data_stereo = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (rate*duration, 2))

audio_mono = AudioArrayClip(data_mono, fps=rate)
audio_stereo = AudioArrayClip(data_stereo, fps=rate)

audio_mono.write_audiofile('mono.mp3')
audio_stereo.write_audiofile('stereo.mp3')
```

Edit: Update workaround to get correct duration of mono file (python 3.7.5, moviepy 1.0.0)

Comment: Could you kindly explain why the fps in `audio_mono` needs to be multiplied by 2? Thanks!

Comment: It was a workaround because the duration of the generated mono file was twice as expected. It no longer works with my current setup, so I updated the original answer.